# где находится fcgid_bridge.c ubuntu?

Tags: nginx, apache, fastcgi

Я хочу изменить конфигурацию в файле `fcgid_bridge.c` т.к мой сервер отдает постоянно ошибку `Broken pipe`.

Мне надо , чтобы предупреждение отдавало вместо 500 ошибки  - 200 й  ответ.
В инете увидел конфигурацию, но не знаю, в какой файл вносить изменения и где он находится

```
/* Now pass any remaining response body data to output filters */
if ((rv = ap_pass_brigade(r->output_filters,
                          brigade_stdout)) != APR_SUCCESS) {
    if (!APR_STATUS_IS_ECONNABORTED(rv)) {
        ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_WARNING, rv, r,
                      "mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in "
                      "handle_request_ipc function");
    }

    return HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: То есть вы хотите обмануть пользователя, скрыв факт существования проблемы? https://i.giphy.com/media/Yl5aO3gdVfsQ0/giphy.gif

Comment: причем тут пользователь  ?

Comment: Если пользователь ни при чём, то при чём тут 500 и 200 тогда?

Comment: `где находится fcgid_bridge.c?` — очевидно, что в исходниках http-сервера apache.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin
где искать конкретно , подскажите

Comment: Ну или вы объясняете так, что мы не можем понять о чём речь. "Мне надо , чтобы предупреждение отдавало" - отдавало кому, если не пользователю?

Comment: Ну и, пожалуй, самое главное — почему бы не найти и устранить саму причину возникновения ошибки «Broken pipe» вместо того чтобы маскировать её 200-м ответом?

Comment: `где искать конкретно , подскажите` — что именно вы хотите найти? исходники программы apache или исходники пакета для вашего дистрибутива?